# Filter is not working on SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have created a SSRS report with the combination of two datasets and I am getting data for these datasets from Share Point List. My Datasets as follows

```
DataSet1 Columns:
1) Assign_To
2) Task_Name
3) Workflow
4) Status

Dataset2 Columns';
1) Assign_To
2) Planed_Start_Date
3) Planed_End_Date

My Report as follow(In Tablix):

Assinged_To   Task_Name  WorkFlow Planed_Start_Date Planed_End_date  Status
Prashant      Task_1        3      7/01/2014            10/02/2014   Not Completed
```

Now, I want to filter the report by `"Planed_Start_Date"` for that I am sending parameter for `"Planed_Start_Date"`, so that I can get records in between specific date. But It is not working as per my expectation. I am sending parameter.
`@Planed_Start_Date >= 8/01/2014`

In this case, I get following result in my report (Tablix)

```
Assinged_To   Task_Name  WorkFlow Planed_Start_Date Planed_End_date    Status
Prashant      Task_1        3                                         Not Completed
```

My report should be null as the filter is not matching with criteria. But I am getting about wrong report, In the above case, desire result should be as follows.

```
Assinged_To   Task_Name  WorkFlow Planed_Start_Date Planed_End_date    Status
```

Please tell me, how Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the paramater value of @Planed_Start_Date in the expression of DataSet2?

Your expression for Dataset2 should be something like:

"Select Assign_To, Planed_Start_Date, Planed_End_Date
From Table Where Planed_Start_Date >= " + Paramaters!Planed_Start_Date.Value

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am getting my Dataset2 from Share Point list, hence I cant use above query.